# Can’t add a torus with a large radius

Tags: modeling

Every time I try to add a torus with a major radius of 1317ft (401.42M), the major radius defaults to a value of around 984ft (300M).
I also tried doing this by adding a torus with a major radius of 131.7ft (40.14M), or 1/10th scale and then increasing the scale in “Item” to 10 in the X-Y-Z fields, but then the ability to scale tops out at around 5 in the X and Y fields and only will allow a scale value of 10 in the Z field.
I suspect the Z direction allows this value because the minimum radius I’m trying for is only 20ft (6.09M).
I’ve also tried starting from scratch by changing units to meters, no joy, then starting again using feet, and lastly starting over again using inches.
Still can’t add a torus without the major radius topping out at around 300M.
I also reset the clipping distances. That didn’t help either.
Suggestions?

Comment: There are hard and soft boundaries for the values. The current implementation of the torus has indeed them for the major radius. It's all fine. You should instead be able to scale in all the XYZ axis the object. Are you sure it is limited to 5? I cant reproduce this behaviour.

Comment: Thank you Carlo, I’m at work at the moment, but when I get home I’ll try doing this again (adding the torus at 1/10 scale, then increasing the scale to 10 in the XYZ fields of Item). This time (assuming I have the same issue) I’ll post screenshots as I go.

Comment: Strange. Now I can’t reproduce the behavior.I started again from scratch and simply keyed in all the values at 1/10 what I wanted in the finished model. Then I just set the XYZ values to 10

Comment: Strange. Now I can’t reproduce the behavior. I started again from scratch and simply keyed in all the values at 1/10 what I wanted in the finished model. Then I just set the XYZ values to 10 in the pop out window under “Item”. LESSON LEARNED: If a Torus won’t come in as large as you need it- key it in at 1/10 the size you want it to be, then go to the pop out tab at the upper right of the display window, make sure only the Torus is highlighted, click on the Item tab, and set the XYZ values for scale to 10, and your Torus is now effectively the size you need it to be.